# Error with chemstyle when convert eps to pdf through TEX root - hyperref problem

Tags: hyperref, memoir, eps, thesis, chemstyle

I'm working on my thesis using [`chemstyle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle). The numbering and the scheme work fine in `memoir` class when `epstopdf` package is not use. Here's the code that is working.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[journal=angew,varioref=false,tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}[hbt!]
    \centering

        \schemeref[TMP1]{t6poca}
        \schemeref[TMP2]{tcta}
        \schemeref[TMP3]{tpa}
        \schemeref[TMP4]{tpa2}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{retroexp.eps}
            \caption{Retrosynthesis of  expanding from}
                    \label{retro1}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

I then use a modified memoir class and separate the sections into different .tex documents. But the error appears:

```
Process started: pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "thesis".tex

This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2015.05.02:1751' -> thesis-autopp.ps

 dvips: Font Times-Roman used in file retroexp.eps is not in the mapping file. </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>

  </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>    </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/psfrag/psfrag.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>. </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvb8a.pfb> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>[1    <./retroexp.eps>

]

 Error: /undefined in --get-- Operand stack: blank --dict:15/15(ro)(L)-- space Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1916 1 3 %oparray_pop 1915 1 3 %oparray_pop 1899 1 3 %oparray_pop 1787 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1176/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:123/200(L)-- --dict:5/6(ro)(L)-- --dict:181/300(L)-- --dict:45/200(L)-- --dict:197/210(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: No such file or directory Current file position is 141251 GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Here's the root file:

```
 %!TEX ROOT=thesis.tex
 \documentclass{UMalChemThesis}

   \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[crop=off,runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage[journal=angew,varioref=false,tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}


 %%%%%%%%%%%
 % List of Schemes

 % not yet know how to make it simpler
 % feel free to change it
%%%%%%%%%%

% to override chemstyle using memoir command
\newlistof{listofschemes}{los}{\listschemename} 
\newlistentry{scheme}{los}{0}

 % make new command \listallcontents to list ToC, lof, lot, los, loacr, loapp
% modify here for any new list
% the order of the list determines the sequence which they would appear in the output
\newcommand{\listallcontents}{{\clearpage\SingleSpacing
\tableofcontents\clearpage
\listoffigures\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listofschemes\clearpage
 \listofacronyms\clearpage
 \listofappendices\clearpage}}


% make scheme caption on top of scheme
\floatsetup[scheme]{style=plaintop} 

 \usepackage{lipsum}

  \usepackage{csquotes}


   \addbibresource{achs.bib}

\author{bk.ong}
    \title{blah blah blah}
    \submissionyear{2015}
  \degree{Doctor of Philosophy}

    % load acronym definitions from separate file
   \loadglsentries{acronyms}
   \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{.7\textwidth}
 \begin{document}
  \frontmatter

  \makecoverandtitlepage
 \declarationpage
   %\abstractfromfile{sample-abstract}
     \msabstractfromfile{sample-msabstract}
    \acknowledgements{Thanks guys. I owe you many.}

   \listallcontents % list ToC, lof, lot, etc...

  \mainmatter

  %\include{Introduction}
   %\include{RESULTS}
  \include{test})



       \backmatter

     \SingleSpacing\printbibliography

     \begin{appendices}
   \startapps
     %\include{sample-appen-manual}
    %\include{sample-appen-try}
     \finishapps
  \end{appendices}

 \end{document}
```

And here's the modified memoir file:

[UMalChemThesis.cls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lm8pa8nmr5t6eqa/UMalChemThesis.cls?dl=0)

The file's tex root is thesis.tex. Chemstyle should have converted retroexp.eps but thesis-pics.pdf, which is blank, is found instead. If I use `epstopdf` package as well. Then, the scheme is correct but the marker 'TMP' is still there.

Can someone help me to interpret the error message? Thank you!

Comment: I get no error if I use an EPS file I had on my system.

Comment: But I use my own modified memoir class. That's when the error comes. I also wonder if separating the section into different .tex file had caused the error.

Comment: Without an example that doesn't show the bad behavior, I can only look into my crystal ball, which doesn't say much, I'm afraid.

Comment: But then if I show it here there are too many files. Is it ok to post so many file on the forum?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! `Font Times-Roman used in file retroexp.eps is not in the mapping file.` This strongly suggests that the problem is that the EPS file uses a font which your TeX system knows nothing about. If you compile with *unmodified* `memoir` does the error go away?

Comment: yes, the problem disappears, despite that the error message for the dvip is there. I have shown the working file at the beginning. The problem now lies at the ghostscript error message, which does not appear in the working unmodified memoir.

Comment: Then compare the two classes and try to figure out where the problem is. The problem in that case is in code not posted here.

Comment: You are not helping. If I could, I would. Thanks anyway!

Comment: How are we supposed to fix something we don't know the reason of? Please try `\usepackage{tgtermes}`.

Comment: nope. the error is still the same. I've found these packages in UMalChemThesis.cls might be in conflict: \RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}

%\RequirePackage{courier}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmvtt}

\RequirePackage[breaklinks,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

Comment: With a test file that i have luckily on my machine, the error raises with package `mathptmx`. You can savely use `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` or `tgtermes` instead. It is also possible, that your eps-graphic is faulty. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: The eps-graphic I have tested on unmodified memoir and it works correctly. all label and the pics are right.

Comment: anyway, changing mathptmx to newtxtext / newtxmath or tgtermes still produce the same errors. I wonder if I can use other package to substitute atuto-pst-pdf.

Comment: I have disable all package and enable them one by one. The error appears when I enable hyperref.

Comment: also, when I disable hyperref and enabled mathptmx. the picture is totally gone. Same case with newtxtext. But, when I change it to newtxmath or tgtermes the picture works fine with correct label.

Comment: So, I almost solve the problem. I disabled hyperref and enabled tgtermes and everything works correctly except that the list title being double. For example, instead of 'Table of Contents', it became 'Table of ContentsTable of Contents'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. The only changes is `mathptmx` to `tgtermes`. And, in `hyperref` option, disable breaklinks and set implicit=false.

Therefore, in UMalChemThesis.cls:

```
  \RequirePackage{tgtermes}
  %\RequirePackage{mathptmx}

  \RequirePackage[implicit=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
```

Thanks to Johannes_B